# compare user entered date with the date field stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website where user can create entertainment programs on a particular venue.I need to check whether there is any program fixed on that particular venue for the start time and end time entered by the user.

I have 2 column names in database named `starttime` and 'endtime' which contains the value in the form of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. I think I need to convert the value stored in the both fields in database to timestamp. But how to write the query.

eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
  timestamp(starttime)>='user entered value'
  AND timestamp(endtime)<='user entered value '
```

Is this query possible.?

Comment: What is the database field type for ``starttime`` and ``endtime`` fields?

Comment: try `between` operator

Comment: @k102 ok.But can i use timestamp(column name) inside the query

Comment: show me the format of the date entered by the user

Comment: @RobertRozas its a jquery.user selects the starttime,end time  and date in seperate fields.I combine date fields and start time and stores in the start column name and second case in the next column

Answer (score 1):

If "user entered value" is unix timestamp, you can use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)(field) function to convert that field to timestamp. If it's not, you have to first convert it to timestamp using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) or similar function. Or you can go the other way, and use datetime value inside the query by converting string to datetime using [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)(date, format) MySQL function.

For instance, if user enters the date in `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm` format, use following query:

> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE starttime >= STR_TO_DATE('2012-02-01 12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AND endtime <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-01-01 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')

Personally I like to use UNIX timestamps inside the query, but that's just my quirk.

Comment: I need to convert the value inside column name of the database to its timestamp value.How can I include this to my sql query

Comment: I actually need this one.that is select * table name where timestamp(starttime)>=STR_TO_DATE('2012-02-01 12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AND timestamp(endtime)<=STR_TO_DATE('2013-01-01 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i').Is this query possible

Comment: Why do you want to convert datetime to timestamp when str_to_date provides datetime format?

Comment: Also - go ahead and try, you won't break anything :)

Comment: Ok,I need to convert the value of the column name into str_to_date.Is this possible in the query?

Comment: Yes - just use column name inside the function call - like ``STR_TO_DATE(some_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`` - is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use unix time? It makes dealing with dates much simpler.

```
$current_time=time();
```

This creates an integer.

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE starttime
BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
```

Comment: I need to convert the value inside column name of the database to its timestamp value.How can I include this to my sql query